# How to return a value from Nested function to main function in R

Tags: r, function, nested, return

I have been writing a function to return the basic statistics based on few conditions.And my arguments are a data frame , few columns to group and 1 arguments to check a particular value for "TRUE or FALSE " and another argument to pass which statistics have to be extracted like Mean,median,unique values,SD,VAR

getstack1<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby,Aggval,distval){

```
      dset<-na.omit(dset)
      Xaxis=dset[,Xaxis]
      Color=dset[,Color]
      Groupby=dset[,Groupby]


      library(plyr); library(dplyr)
      if(distval=="true"){

        if(Aggval =="count"){

          countfunc<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby){
            library(plyr)
            stackval3 <-- ddply(dset, c(Xaxis,Color), .fun = function(xx){ Ln=length(unique(xx[,Groupby],na.rm=TRUE))})
            assign("stackval3", "stackval4", envir = .GlobalEnv)

          }

          # A=countfunc(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)
          # return(A)

          return(stackval3)

        } 
        }
    }
```

Now my main function is "getstack1", and the actual arguments are getstack1(sbarr,"workclass","sex","age","count","true")

if(distval=="true") then validating Aggval,If it is count, execute the inner function countfunc and return the value to main function. I have been facing difficulties to return the value stackval3 from inner to main function.

I even tried to assign the value as Global using 
stackval3 <--
assign("stackval3", "stackval4", envir = .GlobalEnv) 
then i tried to call the function outside and passing the arguments.

## A=countfunc(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)

## return(A)

But negative. It would be if you share some methods or code to retune the value of stackval3 to main function.

I have return other statistics using a simple if else , I gone for function because of the need unique values.
Thanks in advance

My data example :

```
> dput(head(sbarr,10))

structure(list(age = c(39L, 50L, 38L, 53L, 28L, 37L, 49L, 52L, 
31L, 42L), workclass = structure(c(8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c(" Federal-gov", " Local-gov", " NA", 
" Never-worked", " Private", " Self-emp-inc", " Self-emp-not-inc", 
" State-gov", " Without-pay"), class = "factor"), fnlwgt = c(77516L, 
83311L, 215646L, 234721L, 338409L, 284582L, 160187L, 209642L, 
45781L, 159449L), education = structure(c(10L, 10L, 12L, 2L, 
10L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 10L), .Label = c(" 10th", " 11th", " 12th", 
" 1st-4th", " 5th-6th", " 7th-8th", " 9th", " Assoc-acdm", " Assoc-voc", 
" Bachelors", " Doctorate", " HS-grad", " Masters", " Preschool", 
" Prof-school", " Some-college"), class = "factor"), education.num = c(13L, 
13L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 9L, 14L, 13L), marital.status = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c(" Divorced", 
" Married-AF-spouse", " Married-civ-spouse", " Married-spouse-absent", 
" Never-married", " Separated", " Widowed"), class = "factor"),  occupations = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 
11L, 4L), .Label = c(" Adm-clerical", " Armed-Forces", " Craft-repair", 
" Exec-managerial", " Farming-fishing", " Handlers-cleaners", 
" Machine-op-inspct", " NA", " Other-service", " Priv-house-serv", 
" Prof-specialty", " Protective-serv", " Sales", " Tech-support", 
" Transport-moving"), class = "factor"), relationship = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c(" Husband", 
" Not-in-family", " Other-relative", " Own-child", " Unmarried", 
" Wife"), class = "factor"), race = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c(" Amer-Indian-Eskimo", 
" Asian-Pac-Islander", " Black", " Other", " White"), class = "factor"), 
sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(" Female", 
" Male"), class = "factor"), capital.gain = c(2174L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14084L, 5178L), capital.loss = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hours.per.week = c(40L, 
13L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 16L, 45L, 50L, 40L), native.country = structure(c(40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 5L, 40L, 23L, 40L, 40L, 40L), .Label = c(" Cambodia", 
" Canada", " China", " Columbia", " Cuba", " Dominican-Republic", 
" Ecuador", " El-Salvador", " England", " France", " Germany", 
" Greece", " Guatemala", " Haiti", " Holand-Netherlands", 
" Honduras", " Hong", " Hungary", " India", " Iran", " Ireland", 
" Italy", " Jamaica", " Japan", " Laos", " Mexico", " NA", 
" Nicaragua", " Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc)", " Peru", " Philippines", 
" Poland", " Portugal", " Puerto-Rico", " Scotland", " South", 
" Taiwan", " Thailand", " Trinadad&Tobago", " United-States", 
" Vietnam", " Yugoslavia"), class = "factor"), income = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c(" <=50K", 
" >50K"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", "workclass", 
"fnlwgt", "education", "education.num", "marital.status", "occupations", 
"relationship", "race", "sex", "capital.gain", "capital.loss", 
"hours.per.week", "native.country", "income"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Small correction . I have tried stackval3 <<- as well for assigning to global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First of all, you call `library` inside the function, including two calls to `library(plyr)`, that's not a good idea. Call `library` outside the main function. Second, you make the definition of the nested function `countfunc` depend on two `if` statements, there's no reason to do that. You can/should define it at the beginning of the main function and make the *calls* to it depend on the `if` statements, the code would be much cleaner. Third, you probably don't need `assign` or `<<-` at all, but this is just a guess, without a dataexample and expected output, it's impossible to tell for sure. A (possibly non-working) revision of your code would be:

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr)

getstack1<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby,Aggval,distval){

    countfunc<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby){
        stackval3 <- ddply(dset, c(Xaxis,Color), .fun = summarize, Ln=length(unique(Groupby)))
        stackval3
    }

    dset<-na.omit(dset)
    stackval3 <- NULL

    if(distval=="true"){
        if(Aggval =="count"){
            stackval3 <- countfunc(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)
        }
    }
    stackval3
}

getstack1(sbarr,"workclass","sex","age","count","true")
          workclass     sex Ln
1           Private  Female  1
2           Private    Male  1
3  Self-emp-not-inc    Male  1
4         State-gov    Male  1
```

You can inspire yourself in the code above, and post a data example and expected output for a better answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rui for such useful tips. I will keep it as a practice in future. I did exactly as per your suggestions, but it is been running for more than 30 min.. Perhaps because of retrieving unique values from a 30K datasets.  Let me see and get back to you .. Thanks again

Comment: @LeninS I forgot, `unique` does not have a `na.rm` argument. And I believe that 30 mins is too much, there must be something else going on.

Comment: Let me amend.. I have posted a sample of data.. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: Post the output of `dput(head(sbarr,10))` instead, like this we cannot copy/paste to an `R` session.

Comment: @LeninS Changed and tested the function. See if this is it.

Comment: Length ( Unique Count)value is displaying as "1" for all the data. So it is not the expected one..Let me try ..

Comment: Hi ..below code worked for me..library(plyr); library(dplyr)

getstack1<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby,Aggval,distval){
  
  countfunc<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby){
  stackval3 <- ddply(dset, c(Xaxis,Color), .fun = function(xx){ Ln=length(unique(xx[,Groupby],na.rm=TRUE))})
  
  }
  
  dset<-na.omit(dset)
  stackval3 <- NULL
  
  if(distval=="true"){
    if(Aggval =="count"){
      stackval3 <- countfunc(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)
    }
  }
  stackval3
}

getstack1(sbarr,"workclass","sex","age","count","true")   ..Thanks a lot for your effort..Much appreciated

Comment: I have assigned the Var into Global env which has taken lot of minutes , I guess.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call` to evaluate in the calling environment:

```
f <- function() {
    do.call("return", list("f"), envir = parent.frame())
}

g <- function() {
    f()
    return("g")
}

g()
```

This outputs `"f"`, indicating that function `g()` never reached `return("g")`, but instead it was called by `f()`.

Answer (score 0):

a toy example

```
f1<-function(a,b){
  if(a<10){
    f2<-function(a,b){
      c=a+b
      return(c) 
    }
    out<-f2(a,b)
    out
  }

}
    f(1,3)
```

In your case

```
  library(plyr); library(dplyr)
  library(plyr)

 getstack1<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby,Aggval,distval){

  dset<-na.omit(dset)
  Xaxis=dset[,Xaxis]
  Color=dset[,Color]
  Groupby=dset[,Groupby]



  if(distval=="true"){

    if(Aggval =="count"){

      countfunc<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby){

        stackval3 <-- ddply(dset, c(Xaxis,Color), .fun = function(xx){ Ln=length(unique(xx[,Groupby],na.rm=TRUE))})
        return(stackval3)

      }

      A=countfunc(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)
       return(A)
    } 
    }
}
```

PS you should return an alternative value in the case your if block is not satisfied,too

Comment: Thanks a lot Federico.. I will try and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

Once you use `countfunc`, you have to assign it to some object to store whatever it's returning. You seem to do that into `A`, but it's commented out.
Once the object is created (e.g. `A`), it's contents is available for you to use inside the `getstack1` function.

What you could do is learn some tricks at debugging. Try inserting `browser()` as the first line in your `getstack1` function. Once you run the definition and use this function, it will stop at that very line and you can inspect or create any object you wish. See `?browser()` for more info on how to navigate when in `browser` mode.

In code:

```
# I usually call all the necessary packages beforehand, but that's just me.
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

# in hopes of making things less confusing, let's confine this function to a global scope
# you can call it from anywhere
countfunc <- function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby) {
  # no need to assign this to an object or explicitly use `return`, the last expression
  # will automatically be the result of `countfun` function
  ddply(dset, c(Xaxis,Color), .fun = function(xx) length(unique(xx[,Groupby],na.rm=TRUE)))
}

getstack1 <- function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby,Aggval,distval){

  dset<-na.omit(dset)
  Xaxis=dset[,Xaxis]
  Color=dset[,Color]
  Groupby=dset[,Groupby]

  if(distval == "true"){
    if(Aggval == "count"){
      A <- countfunc(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)
    } 
  }

  # if distval and Aggval evaluated to desired values,
  # you can extract data from A from here on and use it
  # however you want - even returning it as the result
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Roman..It is very useful and informative. I will keep you words in mind . I will try out the method and share the feedback.. Thanks for your time